# Python vs. Cython loops

Tags: python, loops, cython

I have two small files called LoopTest.pyx as follows:

```
import time
t0= time.process_time()

class Loop():

     def __init__(self, n0):
         self.n0 = n0

     def test(self):

         cdef long long int a = 0
         for i in range(self.n0):
             a += i

         self.a = a
         self.t1 = time.process_time() - t0

         print("Total is %f: and elapsed time is %f" %(self.a,self.t1))
```

and LoopTestPy.py as follows:

```
import time
t0= time.process_time()

class Loop():

    def __init__(self, n0):
        self.n0 = n0

    def test(self):

        a = 0
        for i in range(self.n0):
            a += i

        self.a = a
        self.t1 = time.process_time() - t0

        print("Total is %f: and elapsed time is %f" %(self.a,self.t1))
```

I created a setup.py file as follows:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(name='TestLoop',
       ext_modules=cythonize("LoopTest.pyx"))
```

and built by running `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`.

when running the following test script:

```
from LoopTest import Loop
from LoopTestPy import Loop as PyLoop

n = 500000; 

LPPy = PyLoop(n); 
LP = Loop(n);

print('Python Loop:')
LPPy.test();

print('\n\nCython Loop:')
LP.test();
```

I get the following results:

```
Python Loop:
Total is 124999750000.000000: and elapsed time is 0.031250


Cython Loop:
Total is 124999750000.000000: and elapsed time is 0.046875
```

It looks as if Python loop is faster than Cython loop?! What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: You're defining `t0` outside of your class and its methods, so you're not testing the speed of the loop.

Comment: Try declaring `i` in the cython vesion as `cdef long long int i` as well. It might no be that, bu if it is, you'd have some type checking/conversion at `a += i`

Comment: Thank you, guys. You made my day. I recently learned about Cython and now I see the impact. It is great. I applied both tips and it is fixed. I tried to run for n = 500000000 and Cython is 167 times faster! Cython Loop:
Total is 124999999750000000.000000: and elapsed time is 0.125000


Python Loop:
Total is 124999999750000000.000000: and elapsed time is 20.984375